# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis; not working for html.listbox in IE

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, ellipsis

My HTMLcode is:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.AvailableOrchestration, new SelectList(Model.AvailableOrchestrations, "Value", "Value", "- select -"), new
                             {
                                 @class = "listbox_100per textOverflow",
                                 @tabindex = "3",
                                 @id = "AvailableOrchestrations"
                             })
```

And css class for "textOverflow"

```
    .textOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;  white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The same is working fine in Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: WHat is your question?

Comment: the property text-overflow: ellipsis is not working in IE browser

Comment: if my list box value is very big then "..." should come at the end and full text will be shown in the toll tip.